# jQuery UI dialog positioning : adjust position top by 20px -

Tags: jquery-ui, dialog, position

I have a **dialog** that gets filled by an ajax call. I want to limit the **max-height** of **dialog** and also allow it to be **scroll-able** if this **max-height** is exceeded. The code below does exactly what I want.

The catch is I can not move the **top** of the dialog from the **top position**. I can move it left and right. I can't use **center** either as the **dialog** is displayed in a large scroll-able window. If I use firebug I can adjust the top property but cannot find where it is being set to zero.

```js
$("#your-dialog-id").dialog({
    open: function(event, ui) {
        $(this).css({'max-height': 500, 'overflow-y': 'auto'});
    },
    autoOpen:false,
    modal: true,
    resizable: false,
    draggable: false,
    width: '690',
    closeOnEscape: true,
    position: 'top'
});
```

I want to adjust the dialog's y position so it is 20px from the top of the window. Any idea what I can do?

Comment: I don't understand what the actual question is.

Comment: @j08691 I want to adjust the dialog y position so it draws 20px from the top of the window. I can only change the y position to top, center or bottom.

Comment: Wouldn't a top margin of 20px accomplish that?

Comment: unfortunately no: but this sorted the problem
http://jsfiddle.net/chrisloughnane/wApSQ/3/
`position: ['center',20]`

Comment: Your solution worked for me!  Thanks.  I have been looking for this as well.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Changing the last value solved the problem:

```js
position: ['center',20]
```

http://jsfiddle.net/chrisloughnane/wApSQ/3

Comment: This ia the perfect one

Comment: Would the points fishers leave this answer alone. It does not need your attention or corrections.

Comment: can you explain how this is working , i couldn't find any documentation regarding this ?

Comment: @varunsinghal65 I have not been able to find any documentation on this either.

Comment: @HimalayaGarg The original question is 4+ years old,jQuery has moved on a lot since then and I can see below you already found an up to date solution. :)

Answer (score 12):

The easiest way is:

```
$("#dialog").dialog({ position: { my: "center", at: "top" } });
```

Comment: For anyone that this didn't work for, in order to get it to position horizontally in the center and vertically at the top, this worked for me. I don't really understand why though:

$("#dialog").dialog({ position: { of: window, my: "top", at: "top" } }); 

(jQueryUI version 1.12.1)

Answer (score 5):

using Jquery UI 1.11.4

```
        var Y = window.pageYOffset;

        $( "#dialogJQ" ).dialog({
            modal: true,
            closeOnEscape: false,                
            width:'auto',
            dialogClass: 'surveyDialog',
            open: function(event, ui) {
                $(this).parent().css({'top': Y+20});
            },
        });
```

Comment: This is the correct version for modern jQuery UI.  Note for width and height "auto" is now the solution rather than autoResize:true,  I mention as many, like me, will find themselves trying to align the dialog and resize dynamically (size and margin and commonly done together).

Comment: This did not work for me with v1.12.1.  It initially set the position where I indicated, then it immediately visually moves back to the spot it was before.  Obviously this implies something is running after the `open` function.