# JQuery Dialog Positioning not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have been trying to position my JQuery Dialog widget using the examples in the API and the link found at [jQuery UI dialog positioning : adjust position top by 20px -](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11230645/jquery-ui-dialog-positioning-adjust-position-top-by-20px). Theyeither cause the dialog not to work or don't move anything at all (usually the former). I am using this on a image map, so i need to move the dialog away from the image link so that it doesn't flash on and off. this is what i have now, but it doesn't move the dialog at all:

```
$(document).on('mouseenter', '#Northeast', function() {
    $('#Northeast-dialog').dialog().position({my:"Center",at:"left"of:window});
});
```

Comment: Use [the `position` *option*](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-position), not [the `position()` method](http://api.jqueryui.com/position).

Comment: `$('#Northeast-dialog').dialog({ position: { my:"Center", at:"left", of:window } });` Frédéric?

Comment: @Nicolas, yup, that's the option I was referring to.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I asked for the fiddle as I thought it was a bit more complicated, but not necessary as you show. I removed the comment

Comment: I tried the position option and the dialog did not move at all

Comment: @rigamonk, so you passed `position: { my: "center top", at: "center top+20" }` and the dialog ignored it?

Comment: yes.
$('#Northeast-dialog').dialog({ position: { my:"Center top", at:"center top +20", of:window } });
does nothing

Comment: @rigamonk, case is important here, use lower-case `center`. Whitespace is also important, remove the space between `top` and `+20`. If it still does nothing, please specify the version of jQuery UI you're using.

Comment: $('#Northeast-dialog').dialog({ position: { my:"center top", at:"center top-100", of:window } }); exactly. no movement

Comment: @rigamonk, for what it's worth, it works for me in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/90uza5yo/). Note, however, that the dialog will not accept to be clipped, so `top-100` will be interpreted as `top`.